# "FATAL EXCEPTION: mainjava.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.nexlesoft.twittermodule.R$id.imgFollower"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, findviewbyid, aar

I have an issue with the `R.java`. I create a library and it runs perfectly on `Genymotion`. Then I copy the `aar` of the library to my main project. The main project is crash in the code of the library.

Here is my library's code:

```
LayoutInflater user = (LayoutInflater)this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
convertView = user.inflate(layout.item_list_friends, (ViewGroup)null);

viewHolder = new ListFriendsAdapter.ViewHolder(null);
viewHolder.imgAvatar = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(id.imgAvatar);
viewHolder.textEmail = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(id.textEmail);
viewHolder.textName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(id.textName);
viewHolder.imgFollower = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(id.imgFollower);
```

Android Studio does not generate the id of `imgFollower`. Here is the `R.java` file:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int imgAvatar = 0x7f0e00fc;
    public static final int textEmail = 0x7f0e00fe;
    public static final int textName = 0x7f0e00fd;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainjava.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
com.nexlesoft.twittermodule.R$id.imgFollower
```

Comment: is it in the xml, did you try a clean rebuild?

Comment: Even I remove all the build folder and build again to create new `aar`, it still does not work. The thing is why it is able to create `imgAvatar`, `textEmail`, and `textName` but not `imgFollower`?

Answer (score 0):

> Android Studio does not generate the id of imgFollower

Well `findViewById(id.imgFollower);` doesn't **generate** anything - the XML layout / resources folder does.

If R.java does not have that resource, then you are missing a plus sign in the XML. For example.

```
android:id="@+id/imgFollower"
```

Or, if you use a resource XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="imgFollower" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try it but the error is still there. I finally find out the reason. There is another `aar` file which has the same name with the `xml` layout.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the reason. The error message is unclear. The reason why it cannot find out the id is because there is another `aar` file which has the same name.

The solution is to rename the xml layout.

Thank you for all your concern!